# Alternative firewalls for Windows (Server)

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall

I am looking for a software firewall for Windows as an alternative to the inbuilt one. Open source, free or commercial are on the table.

Most commercial software firewalls seem targeted at home users, and some such as ZoneAlarm don't seem to support Windows Server 2008. My requirements are relatively simple:

- I can reject traffic for port X on NIC 1, but allow it on NIC 2
- Works on Windows Server 2008
- When I install it, it shouldn't disable RDP, or else I have a long trip to the data center :)

My basic goal is that from the internet, all traffic for ports other than port 80 or VPN should be rejected, but once connected via VPN all traffic will be allowed.

Comment: Is there a special reason you don't want to use the Windows Server built-in's firewall?

Comment: @splattne to be honest, I find it very confusing and with too much noise :) Mostly I can't figure out how to bind policies to specific NIC's

Comment: Just bind the policy to the right networks (the ones on the nic you want to bind to)?

Comment: are you looking for software only, no hardware?

Comment: For what it's worth - I don't believe it's possible to bind different policies to different interfaces in Microsoft's built-in firewall.  The most restrictive policy is applied to all interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try [wipfw](http://wipfw.sourceforge.net/) - the Windows port of ipfw (from BSD).

Answer (score 2):

Check out Kerio's [WinRoute Firewall](http://www.kerio.com/firewall). Windows Server 2008 is supported. It's a commercial product, but reasonably priced.

Comment: I installed this on my server and the first thing it did was disable the RDP connection :-(